# How to get this value into custom arraylist in servlet?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have done this ajax code to send data from jsp to servlet.

My ajax code in jsp is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#process").click(function(){

    console.log($("#processlist").val());

        $.ajax({

            url: "processtimesheet.do",
            type : 'POST',
            data : {processlist : $("#processlist").val()},
            success : function(response){
                alert(response);
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

The value in JSP is getting picked from the below EL.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="processlist" id="processlist" value="${timesheetList}">
```

I am getting the values in the servlet..

[com.manager.model.Timesheet@a2a87e, com.manager.model.Timesheet@e3eda6, com.manager.model.Timesheet@74c85, com.manager.model.Timesheet@130bc16]

How do I convert these values back into List ?

Comment: Do you mean array to list?

Comment: @px5x2 Yes I need to convert that array to list.

Comment: You can use `Arrays.toList(array)`

Comment: @px5x2 it converts the list to List<String>. I want it to be converted to List<Timesheet>

Comment: Just convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click and inspect near that hidden input element, you can see that input, in fact, has the value like com.manager.model.Timesheet@a2a87e, com.manager.model.Timesheet@e3eda6, com.manager.model.Timesheet@74c85, com.manager.model.Timesheet@130bc16 . The data is unusable.

This means you embedded full object to the input field. You can instead use/embed any unique field of `Timesheet` type and return that list to servlet. Then you can identify which list is selected at server side.

Assuming you have `id` field in `Timesheet` class, construct an id list:

```
<input type="hidden" name="processlist" id="processlist" value="${timesheetIdList}">
```

And servlet:

```
Map<Integer, Timesheet> index = ...;// map (unique index) construction
List<Timesheet> listSelected = new ArrayList<>;
for(int i = 0; i<idarray.length; i++) {
  if(index.containsKey(idarray[i])) {
    listSelected.add(index.get(idarray[i]))
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I dont have ids for my Timesheet list items?

Comment: Then you have to provide a unique way to convert between your actual POJO and html value. That is a matter of choice.